# Building many-to-many relationship off of another?

Tags: database, database-design

I am currently writing my first database to be used in a Testing Center.  I am having some confusion on how to model a certain relationship:

I have a many to many relationship between Students and Courses.  Courses have a one to many with Exams.  The thing I'm working on now is Students and Exams, which needs to store specific information on each student's exams.

Is it possible and logical to have a many to many relationship that stems from another?  Is there an easier way to do this that follows normalization?

Comment: It sounds like you need what's called an *intermediate table* that captures the two one-to-many relationships into the many-to-many you are describing.

Comment: If you are referring to the table, in this instance Student Courses, that facilitates a many-to-many relationship, my question is if it is possible and logical to have a second intermediate table that feeds off of StudentCourses and Exams.

Comment: I think the design would lead to a student_exam table. Given that the exam table would have, theoretically, a key of exam_id, that would serve as the foreign key back to the exams table, which in turn has the course_id foreign key back into courses.

Comment: So instead of having a student_course table, I should just have a student_exam table since exams already reference courses.  That should work.  Thanks!

Comment: I think that's reasonable. Now, keep in mind that a student_course table might be reasonable from a perspective unrelated to the exams - think in terms of just enrollment, eg student -> courses.

Comment: So if there were cases that needed that, it wouldn't be redundant to have both a student_course table and a student_exam table given that the primary keys of exam is the foreign keys from courses plus the exam number?

Comment: Not really, The two tables provide slightly different information. Student_courses tells you the courses a student is enrolled in, directly. student_exam gives you student and exam info, but course info only *indirectly*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go over the relationships.

- A student takes 1 or more courses.
- A course has 1 or more students.
- A course provides 1 or more exams.
- A student takes 1 or more exams.
- An exam is taken by 1 or more students.
- An exam is associated with a course.

Student, Course, and Exam are object tables.

```
Student
-------
Student ID
Student Name
...

Course
------
Course ID
Course Name
...

Exam
----
Exam ID
Course ID
...
```

Course ID is a foreign key.  This is a one to many relationship between Course and Exam.  A course has 1 or more exams.  An exam is associated with a course.

Since we have a many to many relationship between a Student and a Course, we create a junction table.

```
StudentCourse
-------------
Student ID
Course ID
Semester Year
Semester Third (or Quarter)
...
```

Now, you had all this in your question.  I'm repeating it so my answer about Exams makes more sense.

```
StudentExam
-----------
Student ID
Exam ID
Exam Time Stamp
Grade
...
```

The Exam table ties the exam to the course, so there's no need to repeat the Course ID.  We have a many to many relationship between students and exams, so we create another junction table.

Either the software or the database has to verify that the student is in the course providing the exam before writing a row to the StudentExam table.

This is 5th order normalization.  You can get the information you need about a course by joining the Course table, Exam table, and the StudentExam table.

Answer (score 0):

See above answer for this question, posted by David W in the comments section:

> I think the design would lead to a student_exam table. Given that
>   the exam table would have, theoretically, a key of exam_id, that would
>   serve as the foreign key back to the exams table, which in turn has
>   the course_id foreign key back into courses.